# Merging ordered Kafka topics into a single ordered topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have N topics as input, each with messages added in ascending delivery date order. Topics can vary widely in message count, date range, partitioning strategy. But I know that all partitions for every topic will independently be in date order.

I want to merge all N topics priority-queue style into a new single topic T. T also has whatever partition count and strategy it wants since the only requirement is that each individual partition of T is still in date order on its own. I then feed T to partition-aware consumers which will consume them and idle between due dates since I want each message to be delivered on or closely thereafter its delivery date. This whole pipeline can stream forever.

I expect tuning issues with exactly how partitions amongst all the N input topics and the single T output topic are distributed, and advice which affects that specifically is welcome but right now I'm mainly interested in the overall viability of doing this at all using only Kafka topics, not a RDB or Key-value store. So some extra I/O moving messages between non-optimal topic partitions is okay.

1. Is this doable with the 0.9 consumer where I can control knowing which partitions are assigned to each consumer, so I can let auto-rebalancing occur while endlessly peek/merge-to-T/commit-offset the oldest message on each actual partition? I must have partition awareness to have a chance of this working.
2. Due to needing shared merge state (the last date added to T), is it better to stick with multiple partition-aware consumers in a single process, parallel processes or multiple servers given where that state will need to be? I favor keeping the state onboard in shared memory not networked in ZK or whatever. On a restart I can get it once and maintain it while running if on a single machine.
3. Am I overlooking any Kafka features that would make what I describe easier or more efficient, like some atomic message move between topics? I know I am going against the grain of its design and this scenario is similar to TS.